# Maskrcnn : add_loss( ) raises ValueError

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I want to retrain MaskRCNN model using Coco Dataset 2014 through Tensorflow.

I pruned some layer in MaskRCNN by layer's name, and want to retrain it.

My situataion is that, after pruning MaskRCNN, when i tring to add loss to pruned Model,

it causes ValueError: Layers could not be added due to missing dependencies.

The code I used is this:

```
loss_names = [
        "rpn_class_loss",  "rpn_bbox_loss",
        "mrcnn_class_loss", "mrcnn_bbox_loss", "mrcnn_mask_loss"]

for name in loss_names:

layer = model_for_pruning.get_layer(name)
if layer.output in model_for_pruning.losses:
    continue

loss = (tf.reduce_mean(input_tensor=layer.output, keepdims=True)
       *config.LOSS_WEIGHTS.get(name, 1.))
model_for_pruning.add_loss(loss)
```

And I got ValueError like this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-542261a0e37d> in <module>
      9     loss = (tf.reduce_mean(input_tensor=layer.output, keepdims=True)
     10            *config.LOSS_WEIGHTS.get(name, 1.))
---> 11     model_for_pruning.add_loss(loss)

~\.conda\envs\maskrcnn\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py in add_loss(self, losses, inputs)
   1079       for symbolic_loss in symbolic_losses:
   1080         if getattr(self, '_is_graph_network', False):
-> 1081           self._graph_network_add_loss(symbolic_loss)
   1082         else:
   1083           # Possible a loss was added in a Layer's `build`.

~\.conda\envs\maskrcnn\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\network.py in _graph_network_add_loss(self, symbolic_loss)
   1482     new_nodes.extend(add_loss_layer.inbound_nodes)
   1483     new_layers.append(add_loss_layer)
-> 1484     self._insert_layers(new_layers, new_nodes)
   1485 
   1486   def _graph_network_add_metric(self, value, aggregation, name):

~\.conda\envs\maskrcnn\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\network.py in _insert_layers(self, layers, relevant_nodes)
   1421       # are being relied on.
   1422       if i > 10000:
-> 1423         raise ValueError('Layers could not be added due to missing '
   1424                          'dependencies.')
   1425 

ValueError: Layers could not be added due to missing dependencies.
```

If, this error related with GPU memory size, how many memory those Coco Dataset needs, and is there any other ways to train with 12 GB GPU memory size.

Thank you for your suggestion. :D

Comment: have you solved this issue?

Comment: Yes, i just changed the GPU which have 24GB Memory

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why it happens, but changing the backbone to ResNet50 may solve the problem.

or you can change

```
if i > 10000:
  raise ValueError('Layers could not be added due to missing dependencies.')
```

to

```
if i > 10000000000:
```

in network.py file